# MimeMailParser Extension IMAP Setup

Tags: php, email, parsing, mime-mail

Currently I have an old script that parses emails, as seen here:

```
// Accessing the mailbox
$mailbox = imap_open("{imap.gmail.com:993/imap/ssl/novalidate-cert}INBOX", $mailbox, $mailboxPassword);
// Retrieving only unread messages
$mail = imap_search($mailbox, 'UNSEEN');

// If no new messages found aborting the script
if(empty($mail)) die('No unread emails found!');

$total_found = 0;
$skipped = 0;
// Now we loop through messages 
foreach ($mail as $key => $val) {
    // process everything
}
```

This works fine other than some encoding issues with Russian (Cyrillic) characters and a few other issues. While I could hunt down all these issues individually, it seems like there are already great mail parsing classes out there. I found [this](https://code.google.com/p/php-mime-mail-parser/), which I'd like to use as it sounds like this gets suggested often.

The example code provided is with the parser is below.

```
<?php

require_once('MimeMailParser.class.php');

$path = 'path/to/mail.txt';
$Parser = new MimeMailParser();
$Parser->setPath($path);

$to = $Parser->getHeader('to');
$from = $Parser->getHeader('from');
$subject = $Parser->getHeader('subject');
$text = $Parser->getMessageBody('text');
$html = $Parser->getMessageBody('html');
$attachments = $Parser->getAttachments();

?>
```

However it seems to need a reference to $path which is confusing me as the emails are not stored in a folder, there pulled from `IMAP`. Would I add `$path = $mail;` in the `foreach` block? If not, what format do I supply the email to the parser in? Do I have to use the same script I already have and save it to a folder?

All the emails are being retrieved from Gmail. I used `IMAP` but could use `POP` instead if `IMAP` wont work.

---

Based on the suggested answer i tried this code but its just looping through x unread emails and displaying blank data for everything, headers and body?

```
    // Accessing the mailbox
$mailbox = imap_open("{imap.gmail.com:993/imap/ssl/novalidate-cert}INBOX", $mailbox, $mailboxPassword);
// Retrieving only unread messages
$mail = imap_search($mailbox, 'UNSEEN');

// If no new messages found aborting the script
if(empty($mail)) die('No unread emails found!');

$total_found = 0;
$skipped = 0;
// Now we loop through messages
foreach ($mail as $email) {
    $Parser = new MimeMailParser();
    $Parser->setText($mail);

    echo "-----------------------------Start Of Email---------------------------------";
    echo "<br /><br /><br /><br />";
    $to = $Parser->getHeader('to');
    echo "To: " . $to . "<br />";
    $from = $Parser->getHeader('from');
    echo "From: " . $from . "<br />";
    $subject = $Parser->getHeader('subject');
    echo "Subject: " . $subject . "<br /><br /><br />";
    //$text = $Parser->getMessageBody('text');
    $html = $Parser->getMessageBody('html');
    echo "Body: " . "<br /><br />" . $html . "<br />";
    //$attachments = $Parser->getAttachments();
    echo "<br /><br /><br /><br />";
    echo "-----------------------------End Of Email---------------------------------";
}
```

Answer (score 1):

That class has another function to set the message content directly. Just call $Parser->setText($mail) where $mail is the message content in your IMAP foreach loop.

Comment: Thanks, i tried that but it didnt seem to work. I edited my code above to show what i tried, i did find this but not sure if its correct or not:

The only streams you can use are STDIN and file resources. Any stream that has requires a specific protocol, such as IMAP or POP, is NOT supported. You will need to download the email to a file first and then pass it to MimeMailParser. 

Does that mean i just have to save the email first before reading it and if so what format, can i just join the headers and body and use put_file_contents and save it as a text file or is there a specific format?

Comment: Based on your code above it should be $email inside of setText not $mail. Does it work if you change that?

Comment: Sorry i tried a couple of things, one was to try both $email and $mail to see if it made a difference, not really logical since $mail is all emails but i tried it anyway, just forgot to switch it back to $email so basically either way does not work

Comment: Looking more closely at the documentation for imap_search it returns the message index not the body so you have to use imap_body to get the actual message content. I found a good example you can follow at http://ahoj.io/reading-emails-from-gmail-com-via-imap-in-php

Comment: The problem is imap_body doesnt contain the header info so i am starting to doubt if this can be done passing it directly and it just might be a better solution to save the file but i am a bit unsure how to do that so i am going to try and figure it out myself but if someone already knows would appreciate the feedback